# What is the different between NSCFString and NSConstantString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I declare the object variable as a `NSString`
But when I use the XCode to look into my object, I saw there are two type of String, it seems that the system automatically transfer to another:

[image]

What are the different between them? Are they interchangeable to one and others. Also, what is the condition two change to another?

Thanks.

Comment: I observed __NSCFConstantString in Xcode debugger for UILabel variable when I assigned NSString* to UILabel* by accident

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They're both concrete subclasses of `NSString`. `__NSCFString` is one created during runtime via Foundation or Core Foundation, while `__NSCFConstantString` is either a `CFSTR("...")` constant or an `@"..."` constant, created at compile-time.

Their interfaces are private. Treat them both as `NSString` and you should have no trouble.

Comment: You will have trouble if you try to compare the two objects with isKindOfClass: it will only work if the __NSCFConstantString is the receiver. Just a heads up to anyone who wants to know one of the subtleties that this implies.

Comment: `-isKindOfClass:` is not used for object comparison, so I'm not sure specifically what you're getting at here.

Comment: well i used it for that so it helped

Comment: Well you shouldn't, because that's not what it does.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan what do you use then?

Comment: `-isEqual:` typically. `-isKindOfClass:` compares the class of an object against another class; it has very little to do with comparing the object to another object.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, `NSCFConstantString` is an implementation of `NSString` that keeps the string data in code memory. Compiler creates instances of it when you use `@"string"` constants. You can use `NSCFConstantString` anywhere an `NSString` could be used due to subclass/superclass relationship, but obviously not the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be an optimization done by the compiler.  I'm guessing that the string that is getting converted to an `NSCFConstantString` is equal to one of the constants that is cached for performance reasons.  Your `NSCFString` is just a toll-free bridged string that can be an `NSString` or a `CFString`.  See [this article](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/03/beware-of-nsstring-optimizations/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

One of benefits of transforming NSString to NSCFConstantString is next example:

For example - in method cellForRowAtIndexPath for tableView if you will write

```
NSString *ident = @"identificator"; 
NSLog(@"%p", ident);
```

than it would be the same address for every cell. But with 
NSLog(@"%p", &ident) it would be different address for every cell.

> NSString ident = @"identificator" is a special case - it is created as
>   a __NSCFConstantString class so all equal string literals will share
>   the same memory address to optimize memory usage. &ident will get an
>   address of a local variable pointing to a NSString and will have
>   NSString** type.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7555194/5790492) to source (comments).