# Objective-C : componentsSeparatedByString:@"" doesn't work as I am expecting it

Tags: objective-c

I want to create a `NSArray` with every character for a `NSString`, the problem is that when I use `componentsSeparatedByString:@""` to get every single character in my array, but I am actually getting the whole string in one single case... why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your string doesn't have a string `@""` this is an empty string. What you want to do is separate the characters like so:

```
NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i < [YOUR_STRING length]; i++) {
    NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [YOUR_STRING characterAtIndex:i]];
    [characters addObject:ichar];
}
```

Characters will now contain each letter.

Comment: Thank you ! Will it also work for non ASCII characters ?

Comment: Believe so as it's just iterating over characters. If this works mark as answer so that other people know. :-)

Comment: Yes I'll do that as soon as possible ! Thank you !

Comment: No problems. Any issues just let me know ..

Comment: It really worked ! Apparently there isn't any problem, but there is something that I am finding strange, in the table, all the ASCII characters are of type _NSCFConstantString* while non ASCII characters (like "ö") are _NSCFCString* is it normal ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220683/what-is-the-different-between-nscfstring-and-nsconstantstring

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work too.

```
    NSString *stringToSplit = @"1234567890";
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfCharacters = [NSMutableArray new];
    [stringToSplit enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, stringToSplit.length) options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
        [arrayOfCharacters addObject:substring];
    }];
```