# Why is NSMaximumStringLength not INT_MAX

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, int, max

While perusing through the `NSString` header file I saw the following.

```
#define NSMaximumStringLength (INT_MAX-1)
```

**Why is the maximum string length one short of `INT_MAX`**? Is this to accomodate for a null terminator (`\0`)? A related article [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482641/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-nsstring-object).

Comment: why anyone care about its value...

Comment: It is merely information and for my educational purposes. @BryanChen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hypothesis:**

> It's to accomodate the `NULL` char: `\0`.

**Documentation:**

In Apple documentation found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSMaximumStringLength) for **NSMaximumStringLength**

```
NSMaximumStringLength
DECLARED IN foundation/NSString.h

SYNOPSIS    NSMaximumStringLength
DESCRIPTION NSMaximumStringLength is the greatest possible length for an NSString.
```

And an NSString is but an "array of Unicode characters" - [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

NSString is concretized into either `__NSCFString`during runtime or `__NSCFConstantString` during compile time- [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220683/what-is-the-different-between-nscfstring-and-nsconstantstring)

- `__NSCFString` : Probably akin to __NSCFConstantString (See memory investigation below).
- `__NSCFConstantString`: uses a char array allocation ( const char *cStr ) - [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html).

---

**Memory Investigation of NSString:**

**Code**

```
NSString *s1 = @"test";
```

**Breaking during runtime in LLDB:**

**Type:**

```
expr [s1 fileSystemRepresentation]
```

**Output:**

```
$0 = 0x0b92bf70 "test" // Essential memory location and content.
```

**To view memory type in LLDB:**

```
memory read 0x0b92bf70
```

**Output:**

```
0x0b92bf70: 74 65 73 74 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  test............
0x0b92bf80: 7c 38 d4 02 72 a2 1b 03 f2 e6 1b 03 71 c5 4a 00  |8..r.......q.J.
```

*Notice empty termination after the last char `t`.

**Testing Hypothesis of `NULL` termination:**

**Added a `char*` to previous code:**

```
NSString *s1 = @"test";
char *p = (char*)[s1 cString];
```

**Break into code with LLDB and type:**

```
expr p[4] = '\1' // Removing NULL char.
```

**Now if we print NSString with command:**

```
expr s1
```

**Output:**

```
(NSString *) $0 = 0x002f1534 @"test
Avg Draw Time: %g"
```

*Notice garbage after the 't', "Avg Draw Time: %g" (aka buffer over reading).*

**Conclusion**

Through inference we can observe that there is `1 byte` in the **NSMaximumStringLength** definition that is left for the NULL char to determine the end of a string in memory.

Comment: Thankyou for your continued research. +1

Comment: `fileSystemRepresentation` does not return the "Essential memory location and content". It returns a "C-string in a format and encoding suitable for use with file-system calls". That has nothing to do with the internal storage used for the NSString.

Comment: @MartinR: I use that address to remove the NULL char and it modifies the NSString which modifies 'internal storage'.

Comment: Excellent investigation.  Accepted answer