# Is it possible to print the memory of a Objective-C, iOS variable?

Tags: ios

I want to know the memory of the variable taking up… Easily, i can calculate the address. Any convenient way to print the memory, for a NSArray, NSDictionary, and others.

Comment: Check this: -[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555143/nslog-an-objects-memory-address-in-overridden-description-method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555143/nslog-an-objects-memory-address-in-overridden-description-method)

Comment: The memory allocated for an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` may not be contiguous so on some cases that would be difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any convenient way to print the memory, for a NSArray, NSDictionary, and others.

The "memory" probably wouldn't tell you much. Foundation's container classes store pointers to objects, so all you'd see is memory addresses. Also, in order to understand "the memory" you'd need to know something about the internal structure of those classes. In fact, different instances of those classes [might not even have the same representation](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html). Instead, you're far better off letting the object tell you what it contains.

You can use the `-description` method to get a description of most objects. This is the usual way to inspect an object. There's also a `-debugDescription`, which is [what the debugger calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9379633/643383) to when you use the `po` command to print an object.